# Append S3 File in Lambda, Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I understand it's not recommendable way but we need to update the same S3 file using Lambda.
We'd like to write and add the count result in the same file in S3.

Usually, it's counting and updating one by one in sequential order in the same job session. But we can't deny any possibility that the scheduled jobs using same Lambda function can run simultaneously, especially at the busy time. In such case, the file can be updated in unintended way or corrupsed in the worst senario.

I think we can set the concurrency 0 of that Lambda function and make it always run in sequential order, but I'm afraid it might cause the performance issue instaed.

If you have any better idea for concurrency prevention or any error countermeasure in Python code below, please advise me.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
-- lambda_handler.py

import json
from s3 import *

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_append('yyyymmdd/result.txt', 'yyyymmdd/result.txt', 'append str')


-- function S3.py    
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

bucket_name = 's3-sachiko-aws3-new2'
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")

# S3 File Append
def s3_append(target_path, append_path, append_str):

    target_context = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, target_path).get()["Body"].read()  
    s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, append_path).put(Body=target_context + b"\n" +  bytes(append_str, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: IMO S3 is not an ideal solution for write concurrency..consider using other options maybe `dynamodb`?

Comment: This cannot be done.  S3 does not provide object locking necessary to prevent race conditions.  You must use some other service, like SQS, or a traditional database, to store the work units.

Comment: How are you _consuming_ the result file? That is, what process is using the file that you are updating? Is it being used continuously throughout the day, or only once per day, or is it merely containing historical information that is not being immediately used? Depending on how the file is being used, we could recommend an appropriate way of accumulating the information and then making it available. It might not require continuously updating that single file -- it might be better to accumulate information in separate files and combine it once per day. More information, please!

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Sorry for late reply. Thanks for your comment. It's our customer's system and bit difficult to use the other service at this time.

Comment: @Anon Coward Sorry for my late reply. Thanks for your comment, yeah,  S3 has no object locking and that means can't avoid file corruption.

Comment: @John Rotenstein Sorry for my reply but many thanks for your kind comment. You're totally right we'd better consider about the actual frequency and operations -- We'd just like to count 30 target table row number with table name once a day (at different timing) and send to the other system.
Output separate files, for example table name and target date, and combine it single sending file would be a good idea. Let us try it as possible choice. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement, you want to do two things:

1. Make a freeform update to an S3 file based on an upstream request
2. Make a simple calculated update to the same file based on the result of Update 1.

If this is the case, you can set up a SQS FIFO queue and push the requests from the upstream system into it.  Then you can set up an Event Source Mapping lambda that will pull freeform updates one-by-one from the queue, make Updates 1 and 2, write the file back to S3 and then pick up the next item in the queue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your understanding and advice. SQS seems to be solid solution. We'll discuss it with our customer for the future.